# How to ignore list root with json/jackson serialization?

Tags: json, jersey, jackson

I've got a simple Bean annotated with @XmlRootElement :

```
@XmlRootElement
public class MyBean {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

I've got a simple jersey service which expose this bean and a list of this bean :

```
@Component
@Path("/myresource")
public class MyResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<MyBean> getAll() {
          //...
          return list;
    }

    @GET 
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public MyBean getById(@PathParam("id") long id) {
        //...
        return bean;
    }
}
```

The trouble is that when i get the list of beans, i've got the following json :

```
{"myBean":[{"name":"Hello"},{"name":"Plop"}]}
```

What i would like is (without the list root name) :

```
{[{"name":"Hello"},{"name":"Plop"}]}
```

Is there a simple way to do that, i did not found any annotation ? I don't want to create a wrapper for the list. Do i need to modify the jackson configuration, or create a mapper, ... ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for your help but i had the same result with an array.

Instead of that, I **removed the XmlRootElement annotation** on MyBean and added the following in the web.xml in the servlet declaration :

```
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

Comment: This is important -- you were probably using one of mapper notations (badgerdfish/jettison, natural), which add wrapper element. @XmlRootElement should be ok with POJO-mapping, although not needed for anything.

Comment: Jersey has spent a lot of time messed up where lists and arrays were concerned. POJO mapping is supposed to fix this but may require some code adjustment.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, if you use

```
MyBean[]
```

instead of ArrayList, you will get exactly what you want!

Hope that helps,

Ohad